# Spotify API group artists / albums

Tags: api, spotify

Does spotify's web api allow album and artist queries with a list of {id}s?
From the docs, the endpoints take in only one entity id per request https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the Spotify Web Api supports both of these; you simply have to omit the `{id}` from the end of the URL. So to query a single able ID you would want `/albums/{id}`, but to query multiple albums you would want just `/albums`. This is common practice in **[RESTful services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)**.

Spotify has an endpoint [**`/albums`**](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/get-several-albums/) which takes in the `ids` parameter in a comma-separated format:

> curl -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums?ids=382ObEPsp2rxGrnsizN5TX,1A2GTWGtFfWp7KSQTwWOyo,2noRn2Aes5aoNVsU6iWThc&market=ES" -H "Accept: application/json"

Along with an endpoint [**`/artists`**](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/get-several-artists/#complete) which takes in the `ids` parameter in a comma-separated format:

> curl -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists?ids=2CIMQHirSU0MQqyYHq0eOx,57dN52uHvrHOxijzpIgu3E,1vCWHaC5f2uS3yhpwWbIA6" -H "Accept: application/json"